# Complex integral related to Riemann-Hilbert problem

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration

**Context:**

Consider the Riemann-Hilbert problem, taken from 
[this paper](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8duubuohok5m942/Trogdon.pdf?dl=0)  on p 49:
$$ \phi^+(s)+\phi^-(s)=s^2-1 \,, \quad s\in [-\ell,\ell]\,, \quad \ell>0\,, \phi(\infty)=0\,,$$
where the functions $\phi^\pm(s)$ mean
$$\phi^\pm(s)\equiv\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\phi(s\pm i \epsilon)\,. $$

As mentioned in the text, to look for solutions to the problem, one needs to compute the integral
$$\int_{-\ell}^{\ell}\frac{1-s}{\sqrt{(s-\ell)(s+\ell)}^+}\frac{ \mathrm d s}{2\pi i} =-\frac{i}{2}(\ell^2-2)\,,$$
note that the square root is considered from value of $s$ hovering just above the real axis as denoted by the $+$.

**My problems:**

1. How do I use in practice the definition of $\phi^+$ to compute this integral. That is what is really $\sqrt{(s-\ell)(s+\ell)}^+$?
2. How do you get $-i(\ell^2-1)/2$?

**Attempts:**

I tried to evaluate this integral by picking some branch-cut for the $\sqrt{(s-\ell)(s+\ell)}^+ = \sqrt{\rho_1\rho_2}e^{i(\phi_1+\phi_2)/2}$, where $\sqrt{(s-\ell)}=\sqrt{\rho_1}e^{i\phi_1/2}$ and $\sqrt{(s+\ell)}=\sqrt{\rho_2}e^{i\phi_2/2}$ with $\sqrt{\rho_2}=|s-\ell|$ and $\sqrt{\rho_2}=|s+\ell|$.

The contour is

[image: Complex contour]

As no poles are enclosed by the contour this contour integral sums op zo zero. However, I have the feeling that this is wrong as e.g. the contribution of the big and two small circles don't seem to go to zero when to limits to $\epsilon$ and $R$ are taken to 0 and $\infty$, respectively.

Comment: PDF link does not seem to load.

Comment: @Qmechanic Thanks, it should be fixed now!

Comment: PDF link does still not seem to load.

Comment: @Qmechanic Third try, helpfully it works now!